# Aligning text inside list elements

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with some li elements i was originally used

i currently have my html

```
<div class="christmas_links">
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

my css

```
.christmas_links{
width:1000px;
margin:0px auto;
padding:0px;
}
.christmas_links ul li{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
.christmas_links li{
float:left;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
width:200px;
text-align:left;
}
```

my issue is even though i have 5 items set at 200px each. when using firefox's firebug the list drops down a line and i have got the width to a maximum of 189px before the last item in the list drops down a line. I had to change the display:inline; to float:left; as i needed the items to be inline but be able to center the text at the same time. Does anyone know why 200px on 5 objects with no padding or margin set doesn't allow the line to be on 1 single line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't removed the default `padding` which most browsers apply to the `ul` element. Simply add:

```css
.christmas_links ul {
    padding:0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pJzae/).

Comment: right, i was under the impression that .christmas_links ul li would of done the same. Thank you 100% correct. i will mark as correct when it lets me.....